# How we make Outlet of label and set text on runtimw

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am creating Project in Xamrin.In main storyboard I am taking label. On widget i am giving name label1.

But How we acess this label . And set text on run time

```
public override void ViewDidLoad () {
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

using Static variation will be good 
in any view controller that you like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


static var labeltext = String()

 }
```

and in another view controller you can use that like here

```
 viewcontroller.labeltext
```

so you can use this static variation to fill label

```
 label1.text = viewcontroller.labeltext
```

Comment: Please How we make IBOUTLet of label

Comment: just go to your story board and make it you can see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-ZaRC8L6uE

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an outlet for that Label, then you can access it directly in the ViewController.

http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2016/3/1/60-how-to-create-outlets-and-actions-in-xcode-using-swift

Or

You can give that label a Tag (for example: 2) in storyboard and then retrieve it in ViewDidLoad like:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad () {

base.ViewDidLoad ();

UILabel label = this.View.ViewWithTag(2); 
}
```